# Migrating log files - should I copy file/directory permissions?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm planning to move the log files for the databases `ReportServer`, `ReportServerTempDB`, `tempDB`, and `msdb` to a new drive.
But it seems that permissions aren´t copied with the directories and files; should I bother to move them over? (Or is that overkill?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't move the permissions too the service account under which SQL Server is running may not be able to access them.

You can use Robocopy to do this quite easily. I tend to use the following.

```
ROBOCOPY <source> <target> /MIR /SEC /SECFIX
```

More detaisl on this command can be found [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2008/07/31/robocopy-mir-switch-mirroring-file-permissions.aspx)

More Robocopy options can be found [here](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Comment: Does `ROBOCOPY /MIR <Source> <Target>` copy both the file and the permissions or just copy the permissions to an existing file?

Comment: I have updated the command to cover the updating of security on files you have already copied.